# how to disable validation for cancel button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

I have a submit and a cancel button in my dialogbox,
when i  click on submit button the validatation works, but I want when i click on cancel button, form to be closed without need validation...Now when I click on cancel button validation fired and for second time  form closed.

**HTML** code:

```
<button  mat-button (click)="closeDialog()" mat-flat-button>Cancel</button>
```

**ts** code:

```
  closeDialog(){
    this.dialogRef.close({event:'Cancel'});
  }
```

How I can close form with one click?
Thank you...

Comment: It's hard to say without actual reproduction of your code on stackblitz. You're mentioning validation and submitting, so I assume you're using a `<form>`. Note that by default, all buttons within a form will have a [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) of `submit`. If your close button is inside a form, try applying a `type="button"` to it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `mat-dialog-close` on your button tag, didn't need extra function

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close mat-flat-button>Cancel</button>
```

[angular material mat-dialog examples](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples)

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pyxymvxvxdx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks, I used your code, but I still need two clicks to close the dialog box.
The second link you sent gives an error ... Thank you for checking

Comment: I fixed second link, please add more code to your question for better help.@HodaJa'fari

Comment: Doesnt work. The formcontrol which is required still show red when dialog is closed.